# Check if class instances are callable without instantiating

Tags: python, class, callable-object

How to check if the instances of a given class are callable? This is easy to do if you instantiate the class and then use `callable()`. But my question is how to check this without instantiating. Take for example the `Calendar` class:

```py
>>> import calendar
>>> callable(calendar.Calendar())
False
```

I want to do the same but without instantiating, i.e. implement some function `callable_class_instances()` such that:

```py
>>> import calendar
>>> callable_class_instances(calendar.Calendar)
False
>>> 
>>> class MyFunc:
...     def __init__(self):
...         print('Should not run on callable_class_instances call.')
...     def __call__(self):
...         print('MyFunc instance called.')
>>> callable_class_instances(MyFunc)
True
```

Is there any simple way to do this which does not look like a hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable):

> Note that classes are callable (calling a class returns a new instance); instances are callable if their class has a `__call__()` method.

The problem with my previous attempt (`hasattr`) was that all classes have a `__call__` method so that we can initialise them. This should work most of the time:

```python
>>> import types

>>> import calendar
>>> isinstance(calendar.Calendar.__call__, types.FunctionType)
False
```

Note that this will not work for non-Python `__call__` implementations.

Comment: the new attempt looks good. Do you know of any class that has a non-python `__call__` implementation? Would be nice to link here to an example for which this does not work.

Comment: Honestly I did a brief investigation before I posted this but couldn't find any. I guess C-based third party libraries (`numpy` etc) might contain examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try to find an example in which this does not work. Will comment here if I find one.